# Link Page AFTER Toggle

Tags: javascript, html, css, gsap

I have a toggle button that animates. After it has animated I want the user to be redirected to a different page. This code comes from: https://codemyui.com/flipping-egg-toggle-switch/

I haven't used toggles before and wasn't sure if there was a standard way to do this.

Thanks!

Code:

```js
var select = function(s) {
    return document.querySelector(s);
  },
  selectAll = function(s) {
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
  },
  animationWindow = select('#animationWindow'),
  animData = {
    wrapper: animationWindow,
    animType: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    prerender: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/35984/egg_flip.json'
  },
  anim;

anim = bodymovin.loadAnimation(animData);
anim.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', onDOMLoaded);
anim.setSpeed(15);

function onDOMLoaded(e) {

  animationWindow.onclick = function(e) {
    if (anim.currentFrame > 0) {
      anim.playSegments([anim.currentFrame, 0], true);
      TweenMax.to('.eggGroup', 1, {
        x: 0,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(0.9, 0.38)
      })
    } else {
      TweenMax.to('.eggGroup', 1.4, {
        x: 73,
        ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(0.9, 0.38)
      })
      anim.playSegments([anim.currentFrame, 300], true)
    }
  }
}
```

```css
  body {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#animationWindow {
  width: 50%;
  ;
  height: 50%;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
  cursor: pointer;
```

```html
<div id="animationWindow">
</div>
```

Comment: You can use `setTimeout()` with the animation timeout and inside the callback to navigate user, or, I don't know the library you're using, but maybe it have an callback to 'animation finished' (search in the docs).

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_animationend.asp

Comment: Might want to include the GSAP tag as well? Would likely help attract those more familiar with that animation library.

Answer (score 0):

From [TweenMax documentation](https://greensock.com/docs/TweenMax): pass function as callback using `onComplete` property. For example:

```
TweenMax.to('.eggGroup', 1.4, {
    x: 73,
    ease: Elastic.easeOut.config(0.9, 0.38),
    onComplete: function(){ ** do something ** };
})
```